# I need to do faster the process that is getting content and managing flag from javaMail.Message type

Tags: android, kotlin, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to slove this problem so long time.
First time , I got the javaMail.Message. I pull the content of mail message and other things in RecyclerView.Adapter -> OnBindViewHolder. But When I pulling content and managing flag , it take so long time.
this is main page

```
val props = Properties()
            props.setProperty("mail.debug", "true")
            props.setProperty("mail.imap.port", "143")
            props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true")
            props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.port", "993")
            val session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, authenticator(mailBox.user, mailBox.pass))
            val store = session.getStore("imaps")
            store.connect(mailBox.mailHost,mailBox.user,mailBox.pass)
            val fetchProfile = FetchProfile()
            fetchProfile.add(FetchProfile.Item.CONTENT_INFO)
            fetchProfile.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE)
            val emailFolder = store.getFolder("Inbox")
            emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE)
            val messages: Array<Message> = emailFolder.messages
            emailFolder.fetch(messages,fetchProfile)
            activityUiThread {
                val adapter = testAdapter(this@MailBox,messages,this@MailBox)
                allMail_recycler.adapter = adapter
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
```

this is adapter

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder : ViewHolder, position: Int) = runBlocking{
    val message = receiveMessage[position]
        /** visibility **/
       // holder.itemView.d3p.visibility = INVISIBLE
        holder.itemView.imV_attach.visibility = INVISIBLE
        /** unChangeable **/
            val bworker = GlobalScope.launch {
            val from = message.from[0].toString().split("<")[0]
            val sentDate= message.receivedDate
            val subject = message.subject
            val content = message.content.toString()
            val recepient = message.allRecipients[0].toString()
            val seen = message.flags.toString()
            val attachent = message.isMimeType("multipart/mixed")
            if (attachent){
                holder.itemView.imV_attach.visibility = VISIBLE
            }
             holder.itemView.mailSender.text = from
             holder.itemView.dateTimeTxt.text = SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd").format(sentDate)
             holder.itemView.subjectTxt.text = subject
             holder.itemView.bodyTxt.text = content
              //  mailBox.data.add(messageModel(from,recepient,subject,content,date,attachent,seen))
            }
            bworker.join()

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        notifyItemChanged(position)
        eventChange.change(position)
    }
}
```

this is my project

[check this](https://github.com/YaWaiAung/My-mail.git)

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by simplifying your code.  Replace these lines:

```
        props.setProperty("mail.debug", "true")
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.port", "143")
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true")
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.port", "993")
        val session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, authenticator(mailBox.user, mailBox.pass))
```

with these:

```
        props.setProperty("mail.debug", "true")
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true")
        val session = Session.getInstance(props)
```

This:

```
        val from = message.from[0].toString().split("<")[0]
```

probably wants to be something like this:

```
        val from = (InternetAddress)(message.from[0]).getAddress()
```

(Not sure if the cast is needed.)

I don't know why you're using the received data as the sent date, but that's wrong.  Why aren't you just using the sent date?

Using message.content.toString is only going to work for a simple plain text message.  Certainly any message with an attachment is not going to give you want you want.  See the FAQ entry for
[find the main message body](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#mainbody).

That will also explain why you don't want to pull down the entire message content every time; it's horribly inefficient.  You might also need to change your program so that any attachments are only downloaded when the user clicks on them.  For debugging, try commenting out the access of message.content and replace it with an empty string and see if the performance is closer to what you're expecting.

If you're still not getting the desired performance, you should look at the other FetchProfile items you might use.  You should also post the JavaMail debug output, ideally with a timestamp for each line, or with output from your program showing System.currentTimeMillis() around each one of the key statements in your program.

Comment: Thank you . Your answer is work for me. But it is need more faster. When I cheking message.contentType() and return the content , it is the main process of taking long time

Comment: So update your post with the current code you're using and wit the performance data I asked for.  In the end, you're performance is limited by your mail server.  What mail server are you using?

Comment: I uploaded on github and edited my post, please check and give me advice, Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to work my way through your entire code repository and debug your program for you.  You need to extract the parts that have the problem, post them here, include the debug output I asked for, and include the performance data I asked for.  I assume you know something about how to debug performance problems; I cant teach you everything from the ground up.